# Calculate $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} {e^{1 \over \ln{x}} \over \ln^2{x} }$

Tags: calculus

I have this limit, and since it is "$0 \over 0$" case, I can use L'Hopital's theorem and when applying it, it seems to me that I go circularly with it (never have the case to finish it).

After L.H.T. I get the 
$$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} {-{1 \over x} {1 \over {\ln^2x}} e^{1 \over \ln{x}} \over {2{1 \over x} \ln{x} }}$$

and then the :

$$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} {  -e^{1 \over \ln{x}} \over {2 \ln^3{x} }}$$

It seems to me that this goes round and round with L'Hopitals ,but the solution should be $0$.
Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think fractions in superscripts are easier to read if you write things like $e^{1/2}$ rather than $e^\frac 1 2$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: change variable: $u = \frac{1}{\ln x}$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since $\log x = (x - 1) - \frac {1} {2} (x - 1)^2 + \cdots$, putting $x = 1 - \varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon \to 0^{+}$, we have $\log x = -\varepsilon - \frac {1} {2} \varepsilon^2 + \cdots \to 0^{-}$. Let $y = -1 / \log x$, where $y \to +\infty$. Then the original expression becomes $$\lim_{y \to +\infty} \frac {y^2} {e^y}.$$ Applying L'Hopital's rule twice, we have $$\lim_{y \to +\infty} \frac {2} {e^y} = 0.$$